# problems with javascript function loading content from other files

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I'm trying to build a functionality in which I only really edit my index.php, I got a lot of other php files with just a form in them or just a few lines of text.
What I want to achieve is to load these other files in the `contentwrapper` of my index.php.

I have been successfull on doing this with an `iframe` and with a html `<object>`.
The problem with these though is that first of all they load an all new `#document` in the DOM, and also my webpage has no set height so `height: 100%` won't work on those and I would get these ugly scrollbars and stuff.

after searching a lot on SO today I found a few interesting solutions which I combined, this is what I'm trying now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="js/csi.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function load_content(target){
    document.getElementById('contentwrapper').innerHTML='<div data-include="' + target + '" ></div>';
    return false;
}

</script>
```

now you may question what `data-include` is, this is a very nice workaround I found on SO.

[THIS is what it does](https://github.com/LexmarkWeb/csi.js), it basically calls a .js file that replaces the containing element with the data that is in the file `(target in the above example)`

I call this functionality like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="load_content('update.php');">Update profile</a>
```

It works as far as adding this to the DOM:

```
<div id="contentwrapper">
    <div data-include="update.php" ></div>
</div>
```

but besides that it does nothing, I think that it doesn't call the .js file for the data-include attribute. But I can't find a solution for this nowhere.

(BTW: the data-include attribute does work if I put it in a tag manually without javascript)

I Hope I didn't overexplain the situation, and I thank everyone that tries to help in advance!

Comment: "I think that it doesn't call the .js file for the data-include attribute" Sounds plausible, the code either never executes because it's not called anywhere or it executes before your `load_content` function is called as a result of the page finishing loading. You'll need to call whatever function handles that data attribute for yourself, at the end of your `load_content` function.

Comment: Yes I thought that also, but I cant find how to do that anywhere, how can I make the file `csi.min.js` run again after my function has run?

Comment: Why aren't you just using PHP includes?

Comment: wouldn't know how to, could you link me something that explains that?

Comment: It's really simple. Just use <?php include('somefile.php'); ?>

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: You were going to use an iframe, why wouldn't an include work?

Comment: I have just tried it and it just won't work like it should. If you are so sure it will, why don't you put an answer down so I can see if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Like I said it's really simple, you just add the php include line and point it to the php file you want to include. Maybe you were using a relative path that starts with "/"? Because that would refer to the root of the home path or drive and not the root of the website. It basically just allows you to literally include the contents of one PHP file into another, which from the looks of it is exactly what you're wanting to do. The reason it hasn't been suggested is because as-per your question it seems as though you are specifically looking to do this on the client-side. That's just unneccessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [csi.js](https://github.com/LexmarkWeb/csi.js/blob/master/src/csi.js) script is only run once after the page is loaded. It just goes over all the elements with the `data-include` attribute and runs the `fragment` function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fragment(el, url) {
    var localTest = /^(?:file):/,
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        status = 0;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        /* if we are on a local protocol, and we have response text, we'll assume
         * things were sucessful */
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            status = xmlhttp.status;
        }
        if (localTest.test(location.href) && xmlhttp.responseText) {
            status = 200;
        }
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && status == 200) {
            el.outerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    try { 
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } catch(err) {
        /* todo catch error */
    }
}

function load_content(target){
    fragment(document.getElementById('contentwrapper'), target);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Then call it like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="load_content('update.php');">Update profile</a>
```

So, the only thing you need is to call this function for the new created element. Pass the DOM element and the url to this function and it will take care of loading the contents of the requested resource in the corresponding element.

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks like the answer that I need, do I need to add this code to my javascript or can I just call it?

Comment: Yes, you need to include this function in your code as any other function. Then call it.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, but what do i need to pass as parameters for this function? if I just call `fragment();` in my `load_class` function it doesn't work

Comment: Just use PHP includes, it does exactly what you need and it's soooooo simple!!

Comment: It works pretty good, needs some adjustments to work good for me, but Thank you very much ;) and @Jonathan the PHP includes don't do exaclty what I need.

Comment: You were going to use an iframe, why wouldn't an include work?

Answer (score 0):

May we assume that you followed this advise from the repository: *The only caveat is Chrome, which restricts access to local files via AJAX. To resolve this, simply add --allow-file-access-from-files to your Chrome runtime.*

If you didn't, and you're using Chrome, then this stands out to me, and you didn't indicate that you'd corrected the security block that Chrome puts in place.

Comment: Okay--so with that out of the way, I'm going to play with that JS myself to see what occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The csi.js only runs on window.onload.
Try

```
<a href="#" onclick="function() {load_content('update.php'); window.onload(); }">
Update profile</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just getting there myself.  Seems like that code could use a refactoring to allow it to load arbitrary elements without the need for the attribute, too.  Extracting fragment() and just using that is a first-glance solution.

Comment: I like that solution, only when I try this nothing happens, and this also kind of defeats the purpose of using a function for this, I will try to put `window.onload();` in the function itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic behind "defeats the purpose of using a function."  Responding to a click requires a function, and loading content into a page element requires a function.  As written the script itself is a client-side substitute for a server-side include (which is actually a better way to do it if you're going to tie everything to the page load).

Comment: Okay, I'll keep messing with it--I thought overflowed had the answer.

Comment: It works for me.  I had trouble getting it to function on JSFiddle, so here it is off my site: http://blindedbyscience.net/CSI/.